# Heroku API 403 Errors

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

I am trying to simply setup Reddis with Sidekiq on my heroku instance, but every time my app calls to the Worker, I am getting this error:

```
You do not have access to the app AppNameHere
```

My Heroku API Key seems to be ok, so I am unsure as to way this is happening

Comment: How are you implementing the call out to the worker?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I figured this out... the wrong API key was loaded as a config variable

Answer (score 0):

What wound up being the reason for this not working was the config variable of `HEROKU_API_KEY` was set wrong

Comment: Ah, yeah. That would do it.